# Can a Logic App be triggered for every new blob using the in-built blob trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a Logic App that has to process every new blob that is created in a certain blob storage. I wanted to use the in-built blob trigger provided by Azure, however it is just a periodic check whether there are any new blobs.

Now, if during the period several new bobs are created, the Logic App run is triggered. I am able to choose the "Number of blobs to return from the trigger", but it always enables us to use only "List of Files" in further actions of the Logic App. I figure that i can probably take the first one from the list if i set the returned number of blobs to 1, however i wander if that is the correct way of doing this.

So my questios are:

1. Is there a simple way of triggering a Logic App for EVERY new blob?
2. If no, then how do i extract the first blob from List Of Files using the "Get blob content" action in Logic Apps?
3. What happens to the other potential new blobs when i set the "Number of blobs to return from the trigger" to 1?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  This should be quite easy to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look at [Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid/).

[Blob storages](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) (v2 and blob only) emit events when new blobs are created:

[Reacting to Blob storage events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview).

From the logic app designer, you can select Eventgrid Trigger.

Comment: Eventgrid Trigger is what i was looking for. Thank you